# Firebase Authentication:Newly created user can't be saved in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication

I was registering users with Firebase, but newly created user can't be saved in Firebase though I've refreshed the Firebase Login & Auth tab.Could you help me fix it?
The code is here:

```
let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .Default) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
self.ref.createUser(self.textFieldLoginEmail.text, password: self.textFieldLoginPassword.text, withCompletionBlock: { (error:NSError!) in
if error == nil
{
   self.ref.authUser(self.textFieldLoginEmail.text, password: self.textFieldLoginPassword.text, withCompletionBlock: { (error, auth) -> Void in

 })
 }
 })
 }
```

[image: Simulator Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try an figure out what is the error is when you try and log in, here an example for the use of the `Firebase` error log:

```
Data.ref.authUser(textFieldLoginEmail.text, password: textFieldLoginPassword.text, withCompletionBlock: { error, authData in
  if error != nil {
    var msg = ""

    if let errorCode = FAuthenticationError(rawValue: error.code) {
      switch (errorCode) {
      case .UserDoesNotExist:
        msg = "Invalid user name"
      case .InvalidEmail:
        msg = "Invalid email"
      case .InvalidPassword:
        msg = "Invalid password"
      case .NetworkError:
        msg = "we're sorry, network error has occurred, please login from the settings menu later"
      default:
        msg = "we're sorry, we encountered an error, please try again"
      }
      let alert = UIAlertController(title: "User Authentication error",
        message: msg,
        preferredStyle: .Alert)
      let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK",
      style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        if errorCode == .NetworkError {
          self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ToMenuSegue", sender: self)
        }
        self.textFieldLoginPassword.text = ""
        self.view.endEditing(true)
      }
      alert.addAction(OKAction)
      self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  } else {
    // Logged in
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ToMenuSegue", sender: self)
  }
})
```

[The full `Firebase` errors list](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/handle-errors#handle_error_messages)